# Latex template is not well-compiled

Tags: pdf, miktex, compiling, texstudio, templates

I've downloaded the [comjnl](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/computer_journal/for_authors/comjnl_latexprep2.zip) template from the "[Computer Journal](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/computer_journal/for_authors/msprep_submission.html)" website. When I compile the template, it generates a pdf file without the page footer. I sent the template to a collegue which has a previous version of latex installed and it compiles fine. How can I resolve without re-installing my latex environment?

I'm using windows 10, last version of Miktex and last version of Texstudio.

ps: I also tried other IDE without results.

Comment: Is the bottom of the page empty, or has it been cut off?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Comment: @IanThompson it's cut off! and the next page has the header shifted down!

Comment: Try putting these in your preamble:  `\pdfpagewidth=210mm` and `\pdfpageheight=297mm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer releases of LaTeX, `paperheight` is taken as the value for the bounding box of the output PDF file. On the other hand, the class sets things up for printing on 210 x 276 paper format.

They apparently use DVI as output, with `latex` and, indeed, `xdvi` will show

[image]

You can cure the problem by adding

```
% THE FOLLOWING LINE MUST BE ADDED OR PDF VIEWERS CUT THE OUTPUT
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{297mm}}
```

somewhere before `\begin{document}`.

Here's the output of a PDF viewer after the cure:

[image]

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\pdfpageheight}{297mm}` seems wrong. At least that should be `\AtBeginDocument{\pdfpageheight297mm}`without the inner braces. But there is no need for `\AtBeginDocument`. It can also be done by putting \pdfpageheight297mm **after** `\begin{document}`. Or use the more LaTeXy formulation: `\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{297mm}`.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum Yes, thanks for noting the mistake. I prefer not to have general setup after `\begin{document}`, which explains `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: But even with this setting, and also with setting `\paperheight` to 297mm rather than 276mm, `\layout` shows that the footer is outside the paper area as defined by `\paperheight`. I think this is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum The class is apparently written with `xdvi` and `dvips` in mind, as the first image clearly shows.

Comment: Also with dvi as output, the `\layout` shows the footer below the lower paper edge, which is a wrong design, even if you print it on larger paper. NB. the original `\paperheight` was 276mm, which is about 2cm shorter. No wonder the footer fell of the paper.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum `layout` can do nothing if the page format is ill-designed. It's clear what the class author's intentions are; unfortunately, they aren't well implemented. The journal will quite surely reject a reduction of the text height.

Comment: so what I have to do? I'm not sure I can modify the template they provide!

Comment: @bjorn Type in the `\AtBeginDocument` instruction (along with the comment I added) and let them cope with the problem. Maybe they'll understand that DVI is an almost obsolete technology.

Answer (score 2):

The class file `comjnl.cls` wrongly calculates the `\textheight`. If you add the `layout` package and the `\layout` call, it shows clearly.

```
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
```

It shows that the footer is outside the paper area. The `\textheight` calculation fails to account for the footer area. Adding

```
\addtolength\@tempdima{-\footskip}
```

before or after

```
\addtolength\@tempdima{-\headsep}
```

will resolve that. But I cannot understand why this would not be a problem on your colleague's system, unless he/she uses a pdf viewer that shows more than the paper size.

Comment: I think that the footer is actually taken into account since `\@tempdima` is set to `276mm`. What I find very suspicious is the line which says `\setlength\paperheight{276mm}`. It should be `297mm`.

Comment: @Piet van Oostrum I don't know why, but with a previous version of miktex it compiles perfectly!